# Create a model for create section - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, codable, uitableviewsectionheader

I need to create a `UITableView` with section, and I have values like bellow:

```
let sectionTitles = ["section-1", "section-2", "section-3"]

let Items = [["id": 100, "name":"jim", "family": "rason"],["id": 200, "name":"jim22", "family": "rason22"], ["id": 300, "name":"jim33", "family": "rason33"]]
```

And:

`section-1` is for `["id": 100, "name":"jim", "family": "rason"]`

`section-2` is for `["id": 200, "name":"jim22", "family": "rason22"]`

`section-3` is for `["id": 300, "name":"jim33", "family": "rason33"]`

How can I create a model for it and I fill this model?

Is any online web site for create model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
struct Section {
   let title:String
   let content:[Content]
}

struct Content {
   let id:Int
   let name,family:String
}
```

Then create the array

```
let arr = [Section(title:"First",content:[Content(id:100,name:"na",family:"fam")])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Model using Class or structure like this

```
struct Section {
    let title:String
    let content:SectionData
}

struct SectionData {
    let id:Int
    let name,family:String
}
```

Create array

```
var arr : [Section] = []
```

And Append Data in Array

```
arr.append(Section(title:”Section1”, content: Content(id: 1, name: "lokesh", family: "hdf")))
 arr.append(Section(title:"Section2”, content: Content(id: 1, name: "lokesh", family: "hdf")))
   arr.append(Section(title:"Section3”, content: Content(id: 1, name: "lokesh", family: "hdf")))
```